# Modifying JSON data

Tags: javascript, json

I have a following sample data, which i modify based on certain logic and return back modified object

```
var obj = [{
  Primary: "Hejrwe",
  TestVal: "234723",
  TestTool: [{
    label: 'xyz',
    num: '23'
  }, {
    label: "",
    num: ""
  }, {
    label: "",
    num: ""
  }],
  TestItv: [{
    label: 'xyz',
    num: '23'
  }, {
    label: "",
    num: ""
  }, {
    label: "",
    num: ""
  }]
}, {
  Primary: "Urwhe",
  TestVal: "32432",
  TestTool: [{
    label: 'abc',
    num: '24'
  }, {
    label: "",
    num: ""
  }, {
    label: "",
    num: ""
  }],
  TestItv: [{
    label: 'abc',
    num: '24'
  }, {
    label: "",
    num: ""
  }, {
    label: "",
    num: ""
  }]
}];
```

I am trying to remove any keys where the "label" and "num" key values are empty strings in the TestTool array, and currently i am solving with the following

```
var newObj = {};
Object.keys(obj).map(function(index) {
  var val = obj[index].TestTool;
  var temp = [];

  for (var i in val) {
    if (val[i].label !== "" || val[i].num !== "") {
      temp.push(val[i]);
      //delete val[i];
    }
  }

  obj[index].TestTool = temp;
  newObj = obj;
 });

 console.log(newObj);
```

In the above code "newObj" returns back the modified object, but if you look at the logic applied i am using a temporary array to store the values and then reassign the to the "TestTool" key.

Is there a better solution for this, where i could delete the values as i go through the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
 var result = obj.map(function (item) {
  var filterLabels = function (label) {
    return label.label !== '' && label.num !== '';
  };
  item.TestTool = item.TestTool.filter(filterLabels);
  item.TestItv  = item.TestItv.filter(filterLabels);
  return item;
});

// console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Btw, here I assume you wish to also filter out the **TestItv** empty values too.

Am also assuming you wanted to filter out **ONLY** if both **label AND value** are empty.

Am also assuming that every object has a **TestTool** and **TestItv** otherwise you'll need to add extra checks for **undefined**.

Comment: yes same logic applies to Testiv and yes "label" and "value" both have to be empty

Comment: @RajPowar - then this is the answer you were looking for. I will update to uncomment out the parts you have confirmed you require.

Comment: @RajPowar - have made it slightly more concise by binding the filtered results back directly onto the object properties. Please mark as correct answer if happy with the outcome.

Comment: @RajPowar - squashed the answer down further by refactoring out the filter() function. See final solution.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `.filter()` to reduce the set into a new Array according to your criteria.

And `.map()` should be replaced with `.forEach()`, and there's no need for `Object.keys()` there since `obj` is actually an `Array`.

```
obj.forEach(function(val) {
  val.TestTool = val.TestTool.filter(function(o) {
    return o.label !== "" || o.num !== "";
  });
});
```

So whenever the `.filter()` callback returns `true`, that item will be added to the new array that is ultimately returned.

---

Here's a full demo:

```js
var obj = [{
  Primary: "Hejrwe",
  TestVal: "234723",
  TestTool: [{
    label: 'xyz',
    num: '23'
  }, {
    label: "",
    num: ""
  }, {
    label: "",
    num: ""
  }],
  TestItv: [{
    label: 'xyz',
    num: '23'
  }, {
    label: "",
    num: ""
  }, {
    label: "",
    num: ""
  }]
}, {
  Primary: "Urwhe",
  TestVal: "32432",
  TestTool: [{
    label: 'abc',
    num: '24'
  }, {
    label: "",
    num: ""
  }, {
    label: "",
    num: ""
  }],
  TestItv: [{
    label: 'abc',
    num: '24'
  }, {
    label: "",
    num: ""
  }, {
    label: "",
    num: ""
  }]
}];


obj.forEach(function(val) {
  val.TestTool = val.TestTool.filter(function(o) {
    return o.label !== "" || o.num !== "";
  });
});

document.querySelector("pre").textContent = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: @RajPowar: `.forEach()` is just a general iterator, sort of like a `for` loop. You can manipulate each object passed in each iteration. You were basically using `.map()` like `.forEach()`. The difference is that `.map()` returns a new Array of values that you return from the callback, so it was actually returning an Array of `undefined` values since your callback had no `return`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this. I just use the delete operator on each object property.

```
var obj = [{
  Primary: "Hejrwe",
  TestVal: "234723",
  TestTool: [{
    label: 'xyz',
    num: '23'
  }, {
    label: "",
    num: ""
  }, {
    label: "",
    num: ""
  }],
  TestItv: [{
    label: 'xyz',
    num: '23'
  }, {
    label: "",
    num: ""
  }, {
    label: "",
    num: ""
  }]
}, {
  Primary: "Urwhe",
  TestVal: "32432",
  TestTool: [{
    label: 'abc',
    num: '24'
  }, {
    label: "",
    num: ""
  }, {
    label: "",
    num: ""
  }],
  TestItv: [{
    label: 'abc',
    num: '24'
  }, {
    label: "",
    num: ""
  }, {
    label: "",
    num: ""
  }]
}];

Object.keys(obj).map(function(index) {
  var val = obj[index].TestTool;
  var temp = [];

  for (var i in val) {
    if (val[i].label == "") {
      delete val[i].label;
    }
    if (val[i].num == "") {
      delete val[i].num;
    }
  }

});

console.log(obj);
```